# Optimizing MySQL for single application, single user

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am using MySQL for an offline application. The queries are only executed from this application. There is just one thread executing sql queries. I am wondering if there is a way to optimize MySQL for this kind of setup.

here is the query statistics;

```
Total   ø per hour  ø per minute    ø per second
4,383   12.14 k     202.29          3.37
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is to reduce the number of connections, which should save you some extra memory:

```
max_connections
max_user_connections
```

Set max_connections larger than max_user_connections so you can get in as the administrator!